# Should IEnumerable returned from OrderBy be evaluated if used multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I'm looking at some code which calls the extension method [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The resulting `IEnumerable` is potentially used multiple times. I've heard that with LINQ, it is better to evaluate expressions if they may be used more than once, because if you don't the LINQ query will be executed more than once. Is this the case here also? (Initially, looking at the code, I didn't realise it was LINQ, but I see from the MSDN documentation that `OrderBy` is in the LINQ namespace.)

To make it concrete, the code looks like this, except the item being enumerated is more complicated than an `int` and there may be many more orders of magnitude more of them than there are in this simple example.

```
IEnumerable<int> Multiply(IEnumerable<int> list, int howMany, int k)
{
    return list.Take(howMany).Select(i => i * k);
}

void Main()
{
    int[] unsorted = { 1, 7, 3, 9, 4 };
    IEnumerable<int> sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(i=>i); // Add .ToList() ?
    for(int k=1; k<=3; ++k) {
        IEnumerable<int> multiplied = Multiply(sorted, k, k);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", multiplied));
    }
}
```

This code has the same output regardless of whether I use `.ToList()` or not.

```
1
2, 6
3, 9, 12
```

It seems slightly surprising that this code could be sorting over and over again. But if it is, and I ought to have the `.ToList()`, the output is the same, so how, in general, should I know that `.ToList()` is required? Is it simply seeing the magic words

> deferred execution

in the documentation?

---

To address @Matt Burland's suggestion that I should test the performance for myself I changed the program to the following (using `double`s to avoid overflow problems).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace OrderByPerformanceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<double> Multiply(IEnumerable<double> list, int howMany, double k)
        {
            return list.Take(howMany).Select(i => i * k);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 1000;
            IEnumerable<double> unsorted = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => (double)(n-i));
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", unsorted));
            IEnumerable<double> sorted1 = unsorted.OrderBy(i => i); // Add .ToList() ?
            //Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", sorted1));
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            double sum = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k <= n; ++k)
            {
                IEnumerable<double> multiplied = Multiply(sorted1, k, k);
                sum += multiplied.Sum();
                //Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", multiplied));
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time {0}ms, sum {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

- without `ToList`, 115ms
- with `ToList`, 10ms

(`sum` is the same in both cases)

Comment: Why not try a test to see what impact it has on performance? Then you could answer the question yourself.

Comment: @MattBurland Good idea -- I will. It's not v easy in the original code but now I have a simple example, it's v straightforward.

Comment: Suppose the contents of the unsorted array changed between executions of the query. What should happen?

Answer (score 6):

When you use Linq expression, the result of the expression is not calculated at the definition of the expression but when you iterate on it.

If you iterate multiple times the result will be calculated (and can be different if the base list use in linq expression are changed).

If you use ToList() and keep the result of the method, the result will be calculated now and only one time, and when you iterate multiple times on the result of the ToList() method you are sure to have the same output.

Comment: thanks and re my last question, how can I tell whether or not to add the `ToList()`?

Comment: You may use ToList() when the base list of the linq expression will not change during execution.

Comment: Like @MikeyMouse said : _And to answer the original question, I would evaluate the IEnumerable before using it multiple times, assuming it's not coming from a really dynamic data source and you wanted really up to date data._

Comment: thanks but that's not what I meant. I meant the part where I asked "how, in general, should I know that .ToList() is required? Is it simply seeing the magic words deferred execution in the documentation?"

Answer (score 3):

"Deferred execution" does not mean the resultset will be reused for the second call. It just means the first element can be returned before the *whole* resultset is evaluated.

So, if you iterate over `IEnumerable` (returned from `OrderBy`) for the second time, it will sort the collection again (and *then* use deferred execution to give elements of the sorted collection one-by-one). The sort happens when you *start* iterating, so it doesn't really matter whether you consume all the elements. This applies to LINQ to Objects - SQL may behave differently.

So yes, since memorizing the "materialized" resultset (from `ToArray` or `ToList`) is typically cheaper than sorting it over-and-over again, you should probably do it. In your case, I'm guessing `Multiply` iterates over `sorted`, and is called multiple times, so it's no surprise you observe large performance advantage when avoiding multiple sorts.

---

NOTE: When it comes to LINQ to SQL, relational databases have the concept of "fetching" - they are able to return first row before finishing the whole query, even for sorting under right conditions (presence of the right index). In that case, it may actually be cheaper to fetch few starting rows several times, than materialize the whole big resultset.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, the contract of the method shows whether it may or may not use deferred execution.

When the returned interface is `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, you should treat it as if it uses deferred execution.

Of course this is not true for all of the methods, but you should program against the contract of the method and not the actual implementation, because the implementation can change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a comment, I'd call the "sorted" variable "localSortedList" (if it was coming from a database) to show that it's been evaluated.

Maybe you could include a comment above the line saying "ToList() called to prevent multiple iterations".

Edit:
And to answer the original question, I would evaluate the IEnumerable before using it multiple times, assuming it's not coming from a really dynamic data source and you wanted really up to date data.